# How can I fetch a value from response of web_custom_request in LoadRunner

Tags: rest, loadrunner

I have a LR script and I am using to make a call on a REST API to download a file. The file gets downloaded successfully but I also need the value of the file size downloaded for verification purpose. Here is what i see in loadrunner console.

```
Action.c(50): web_custom_request("GetImage") was successful, 2373709 body bytes, 528 header bytes, 99 chunking overhead bytes.
```

How can I get the value 2373709?? I tried using the below code but the size it returns is a little bit different from the above mentioned and is not solving the purpose.

```
HttpDownLoadSize=web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_DOWNLOAD_SIZE); 
lr_output_message("File Size %i", HttpDownLoadSize);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: So is there no way to get just the value of body bytes in Load Runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_INFO_DOWNLOAD_SIZE` property stores the last HTTP response total download size. This includes total size of headers and bodies of all responses, and possible communication overhead. `2373709 body bytes` is the total body size of all responses got in a particular step, so if there are several requests/responses in your custom request step, this number will be greater then the actual file size.

I'd suggest validating your response body size. There is no standard API to retrieve it though (at least, in LR 12.53, the latest available version). As far as I see, your response is chunked so I cannot suggest you any efficient methods to do this. Here is rather  inefficient method based on storing the whole body to a temporary buffer (twice!):

```
unsigned long length = 0;
char* tmp = 0;

web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=Body", 
    "LB=", 
    "RB=",                  
    SEARCH_FILTERS, 
    "Scope=Body",
    "RelFrameID=1",
    LAST);

web_custom_request(...);

lr_eval_string_ext("{Body}", strlen("{Body}"), &tmp, &length, 0, 0, -1);
lr_output("body length is %d", length);
lr_eval_string_ext_free(&tmp);
```

Also you might need to increase the maximum HTML parameter length using [web_set_max_html_param_len()](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/function_reference/Content/web/lrFr_web_set_max_html_param_len.htm).

However, if you had a non-chuncked non-compressed response containing `Content-Length` header, you could validate it more efficiently:

```
web_reg_find("Text=Content-Length: 2373709",
    "Search=Headers",
    "RelFrameID=1",
    LAST);
web_custom_request(...);
```

Comment: Well I was about to answer my own question as I had found a solution when i noticed your post. What you have mentioned is correct and I did the same thing. I used 'lr_eval_string_ext' to get the length of the body bytes and that indeed solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your response.